# Как передать в параметрах интерфейса ДТО (или другую сущность)

Tags: php, ооп, di

Есть у меня Сервис который имплементирует интерфейс

```php
class EmployeesService implements ServiceInterface
{

    /**
     * @param EmployeeDTO $data
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function addNewItem(EmployeeDTO $data): JsonResponse
    {
        .....
    }
```

и сам интерфейс

```php
interface ServiceInterface
{
    public function getList();

    public function getItemById(int $id);

    public function addNewItem(mixed $data);

    public function updateItem(mixed $data, int $id);

}
```

Возможно ли (обертку добавить или как иначе) описать в интерфейсе метод `addNewItem` так чтобы он принимал параметр `DataTransferObject $data` а вот сами реализации методов могли принять дочерний класс  (EmployeeDTO) разный в разном случае т.е.:

```php
class EmployeesService implements ServiceInterface
{
    public function addNewItem(EmployeeDTO $data)
    {
        .....
    }
```

```php
class SomeAnotherService implements ServiceInterface
{
    public function addNewItem(SomeAnotherDTO $data)
    {
        .....
    }
```

Comment: что вы ожидаете тут в ответ увидеть кроме наследования и интерфейсов? Либо `EmployeeDTO extends DataTransferObejct` либо `implements`

Comment: У меня все классы DTO наследуют DataTransferObejct, но в сервисе ругается, говорит "ты сказал что должен быть DataTransferObejct, а сам передаешь EmployeeDTO" хотя повторюсь EmployeeDTO наследует DataTransferObejct

Comment: да, что-то пхп сие запрещает

Comment: а зачем вам надо изменить тип параметра в дочерних сервисах? Принять-то методы и так могут ваши параметры, вопрос в том, что декларацию не сузить (ограничить дочерним типом). В целом если реализуешь интерфейс, то и реализовывать должен в том виде, в каком написано, сужать типы тут нелогично.

Comment: Мне нужно либо не определять тип параметра, что плохо, ибо могут наопределять в реализации массивы, стдхи и т.д. Либо для каждого сервиса делать свой интерфейс который будет описывать параметры как нужно мне, это я считаю - слишком много букв, поэтому ищу может есть вариант оптимальнее

Comment: Если массивы не устраивают (что очевидно) тогда почему пишите `addNewItem(mixed $ data)` а не `addNewItem(DataTransferObject $data)` ?